# malloc関数について

Tags: c

C言語を勉強中の者です。
参考書にて下記のmalloc関数のプログラムが書かれていたのですが、
`str = (char *)`の部分から何がどう行われているのかわかりません。

説明できる方よろしくお願いいたします。

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *str;
   int num,i;

   printf("何文字のAを用意しますか？\n");
   scanf("%d",&num);

   str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (num+1));
   if(!str){
     printf("メモリを確保できませんでした。\n");
     return 1;
   }


   for(i=0;i<num;i++){
       *(str+1) = 'A';
   }
   *(str+num) = '\n;
   printf("%sを用意できました。\n",str);

   free(str);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*(str+1) = 'A';` の部分ですが、`*(str+i) = 'A';` でしょう(`+1`ではなく`+i`)。写し間違いでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` の話をする前に確認事項ですが [c](/questions/tagged/c) において「文字列」とは

- `char` の配列、ないしは相当する連続領域で
- `'\0'` 文字で終了するもの
- があるとき、その先頭アドレス（先頭要素へのポインタ右辺値）をもって「文字列」とする

です。

```
char hello[] = "Hello!";
```

であれば真に配列です。コンパイラが、ソースコード上には書かれていない `'\0'` 文字を `!` の後ろにくっつけることを行っているので、先の「文字列」の条件を満たしています。ちなみに、この配列変数 `hello` は合計７文字分の配列となります。

さて `malloc(n)` が何をするかというと

- 最低 `n` バイトの連続したメモリ領域をどこかに取得します
- ここでいう「バイト」とは `char` １個が格納できる大きさのことを言います
- その先頭アドレス（先頭要素へのポインタ右辺値）を返却します
- よって `malloc(n)` が返してきた値（＝連続メモリ領域）には最低 `n` 文字が格納できます
- (最低 `n` 文字ということは) `n+1` 文字は格納できない前提で処理を行う必要がある

ここまで、先の「文字列」の条件の最初と最後のものに合致していますよね。更に「文字列」のもう一つの条件である `'\0'` があることを満たしてやれば `malloc()` の結果を「文字列」として扱うことができます。

- `num` 文字の `'A'` を格納し
- その後ろに `'\0'` を追加格納したい
- のであれば `malloc()` の引数には `num+1` を渡す必要がある

とまでわかれば解説になるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

コメントを加えてみました。
参考になれば幸いです。

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int
main(void) {
    // 変数を宣言しています
    char *str;
    int num, i;

    // ユーザーからの入力を受け付けています
    // 変数numに用意するAの個数が入力されます
    printf("何文字のAを用意しますか？\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    // 本来ならここら辺で入力値のバリデーションを行うべきですが何もしていないようです

    // char *型のポインタ変数strに、mallocで確保したメモリのアドレスを代入しています
    // 
    // mallocの引数には確保するメモリのバイト数を渡します
    // sizeof(char)でcharのバイト数がわかります
    // そのバイト数に(num+1)分の値をかけています
    // charのバイト数は1バイトなのでnumが10だった場合、1*(10+1)、つまり11バイト分のメモリが確保されます
    // (num+1)で+1しているのは文字列を終端するnull文字のためです
    // 
    // mallocは戻り値でvoid *を返します
    // このコードでは明示的にmallocの戻り値を(char *)でキャストしているようです
    // Cでは暗黙の型変換が行われるので、このキャストを外しても動作には影響がありません
    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (num+1));

    // mallocの戻り値をチェックしています
    // mallocはメモリの確保に失敗したときにNULLを返します
    // NULLの定義は処理系依存ですが(void *)0で表現されることが多いです
    // 
    // if (!str) {}
    // 
    // このif文はstrがNULLだった時に真になります
    // つまり、メモリの確保に失敗したら真になります
    if(!str){
        // メモリの確保に失敗しているのでエラーメッセージを表示しています
        // 普通はstderrに出力しますが、このコードではstdoutに出力しているようです
        printf("メモリを確保できませんでした。\n");

        // プログラムの処理に失敗したので1を返します
        // main関数では成功時に0、失敗時にそれ以外を返します
        // この値はbashなどではecho $?で確認できます
        return 1;
    }

    // for文でstrに値をセットしているようです
    // しかし、このfor文の内容はあまり意味がありません
    // ループをnum回まわしていますが、やってることは無意味です
    // *(str+1) は str[1] のシンタックスシュガーです
    // つまり、*(str+1)はstr[1]と同じです
    // 添え字が1なので、ループで回してもずっとstr[1]にアクセスしています
    // str[1]に文字'A'がnum回分代入されます
    // 
    // おそらくこれはstr[i]の間違いでしょう
    // str[i] = 'A'
    // にすればstrの0からnum-1までに文字'A'が代入されます
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
        *(str+1) = 'A';
    }

    // strのnum文字目に改行を代入しています
    // *(str+num) は str[num] と同じです
    // 
    // おそらくですが、これは
    // *(str+num) = '\0'
    // の間違いでしょう
    *(str+num) = '\n';

    // 初期化したstrを出力していますが、この出力はうまくいきません
    // mallocはメモリを初期化せずに確保します
    // つまり、確保したメモリにはデタラメな値が入っています
    // Cの文字列はnull終端されていないとただしく出力できません
    // 今までの処理の中でnull文字を代入している処理はないので、printfは正しく機能しません
    // 
    // 正しく機能させるには
    // str[num] = '\0'
    // でstrをnull終端する必要があります
    printf("%sを用意できました。\n",str);

    // 確保したメモリを開放しています
    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

これでコンパイルしてみてください。

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *str;
   int num,i;

   printf("何文字のAを用意しますか？\n");
   scanf("%d",&num);

   str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (num+1));

   printf("アドレス %p に %d 文字 + 1 分の　データ領域を確保しました。\n",str,num);

   if(!str){
     printf("データ領域（メモリ）を確保できませんでした。\n");
     return 1;
   }


   for(i=0;i<num;i++){

     printf("アドレス %p に A を書き込みます\n",str+i);

       *(str+i) = 'A';
   }
   printf("アドレス %p に null ('\\0') を書き込みます\n",str+num);

   *(str+num) = '\0';

   printf("%s\n",str);
   printf("を用意できました。\n");

   free(str);

   return 0;
}
```